# google-http-java-client usage for android

Tags: java, android, google-http-client

Has anyone used [google http client for android](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-http-client-android3) recently. I downloaded the latest [version](https://google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/files/google-http-java-client-1.12.0-beta.zip), but missing the jar.

```
google-http-client-android3-1.12.0-beta.jar
```

According to the doc, I need to import

```
google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android2-1.12.0-beta.jar (only for SDK >= 2.1)
google-http-client-android3-1.12.0-beta.jar (only for SDK >= 3.0)
gson-2.1.jar
guava-11.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Download [google-http-java-client-1.12.0-beta.zip](http://google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/files/google-http-java-client-1.12.0-beta.zip) and extract it on your computer. Read the readme.html for directions. This zip file contains the client library class jars and their associated source jars for each artifact. Similarly the class and source jars for the dependencies are found in the dependencies folder, including licenses.

Eclipse users will want to set the "Source attachment" for each class jar to its corresponding "-sources" jar.

For Android, it is important to know which dependencies are compatible with Android and specifically which SDK level. The following are the jars from the dependencies folder required for android applications (or a newer compatible version of each dependency):

```
google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android2-1.12.0-beta.jar (only for SDK >= 2.1)
google-http-client-android3-1.12.0-beta.jar (only for SDK >= 3.0)
gson-2.1.jar
guava-11.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
```

**WARNING:** for Android, the jars MUST be placed in a directory named "libs" for the APK packager to find them. Otherwise, you will get a NoClassDefFoundError at runtime.

Comment: looks like they updated the instruction inside the zip file but not on the site. thanks